# D7: copy data from node to node

Tags: entities

I got a content type 'activities' with a text field called 'transport'.
When a users submit a new activity, I want them to be able to copy data from earlier activities: just recycling data in other words.

Example:
Activity1 has a field ('transport') that contains text.
Activity2 has an empty field 'transport'.
Is there an easy way for a user to copy the data from Activity1 to Activity2?
The less clicks the better. What's the best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was asked before. Sadly, I can't find it now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but if I was in this situation I will do that way:
hook_form_alter => use a sql query to get the last node id of his last post, then node_load() and in form_alter copy the data you got from node_load() into the new node.

This solution should work if you already have a value in at least one of the previous one.

```
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    //get your form id of the admin activity page
    drupal_set_message($form_id); //or echo $form_id; it should be activity_node_form
    if($form_id == 'activity_node_form'){
        $form['#submit'][] = 'YOURMODULENAME_submit';
    }

}

function YOURMODULENAME_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
    if(isset($form_state['values']['field_activitiy'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])){
        if(empty($form_state['values']['field_activitiy'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])){
           $lastNode =  YOURMODULENAME_query();

           $node = node_load($lastNode['entity_id']);
           if(isset($node->field_activitiy[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])){
                $form_state['values']['field_activitiy'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $node->field_activitiy[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
           }
        }
    }
}

function YOURMODULENAME_query(){
    global $user;

    $query = db_select('node', 'n');
    $query->join('field_data_field_activity', 'a', 'n.nid = a.entity_id');
    $query->condition('n.uid',$user->uid,'=');
    $query->fields('a', array('entity_id'));
    $query->orderBy('a.entity_id', 'DESC');
    $query->range(0,1);
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
    return $result;
}
```

Tell me if you got an error.
PS:once you got the form_is remove the line

```
drupal_set_message($form_id);
```

Comment: Namari, I want to give it a try but I'm completely new to this hook thing. Looking for Hooking For Dummies now. If you got any suggestions...

Comment: I create a module for you, have a try (see above)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the "[Node clone](https://drupal.org/project/node_clone)" module, and make a hook to reset the fields you want to be empty.

[Edit after comment]

Well you say "When a users submit a new activity, ...", so that would work for future node creation. Instead of using /node/add/activity, you should use the link /node/XXX/clone.

To update existing nodes, I see two options:

- SQL request: not sure you can determine which Activity Transport mapping...
- add a select list with the list of all your "activities" (or an autocomplete field, depending of how many activities you have), on change of this list, make an AJAX call sending the activity NID as parameter. The AJAX function should return the "transport" field value of this node, then you can replace it in the current activity form.

I hope I'm understandable :p

Comment: Matt, I'm not sure I can use the node clone module because the second node is already there. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks Matt.
Everything makes sense to me except for the AJAX call. I know how to add a select list but do I make an AJAX call? Where do I put the AJAX function? I suppose I have to create a module first?

Comment: Filip, while looking for the code of AJAX call, i found this: [ajax_call_example](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example.module/function/ajax_example_dependent_dropdown/7) i think that's what you are looking for